# Using geometry with srid 4326, what unit of measure does STDistance return?

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

So here is my set up:

I have a table such as:

`Id, Lat, Long, GeoPoint, GeomPoint`

both `GeoPoint` (geography) and `GeomPoint` (geometry) are set to SRID 4326

I have the following query:

```
    DECLARE @radiiCollection TABLE 
      ( [ID]       INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
       [Radius]   GEOMETRY, 
       [RefPoint] GEOMETRY, 
       [RefAddr]  VARCHAR(255), 
       [MinLat]   VARCHAR(255), 
       [MaxLat]   VARCHAR(255), 
       [MinLng]   VARCHAR(255), 
       [MaxLng]   VARCHAR(255)) 

    DECLARE @point GEOMETRY = geometry::Point(-111.84493459999999, 33.3902569, 4326) 
    DECLARE @gpoint GEOGRAPHY = geography::Point(33.3902569, -111.84493459999999, 4326);

    INSERT INTO @radiicollection 
                (radius, 
                 refpoint, 
                 refaddr, 
                 maxlat, 
                 maxlng, 
                 minlat, 
                 minlng) 
    VALUES      ( @point.MakeValid().STBuffer(16093.40), 
                  @point, 
                  '10 miles of 85210', 
                  33.51734689767781, 
                  -111.6923852740045, 
                  33.26298081643247, 
                  -111.99703818130439 ) 

    SELECT 
      GeomPoint, 
      GeoPoint
     INTO #temp 
    FROM ( 
      SELECT row_number() OVER ( 
          PARTITION BY [ds].[ADDR], 
          [ds].[APT], 
          [ds].[ZIP] ORDER BY [ds].[IND_ID] ASC 
          ) recid1, rGeop1.geompoint, rgeop1.GeoPoint 
      FROM [r].[main] ds 
      JOIN [r].[GeoPoint] rGeoP1 
        ON rGeoP1.[UID] = ds.[UID] 
      JOIN @radiiCollection rr 
        ON GeomPoint.STWithin(rr.radius) = 1 
      WHERE 1 = 1 
        AND ( 
          ( 
            ( 
              ( 
                try_cast(latitude AS DECIMAL(9, 1)) BETWEEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 1), 33.26298081643247)
                  AND CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 1), 33.51734689767781) 
                AND try_cast(longitude AS DECIMAL(9, 1)) BETWEEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 1), - 111.99703818130439)
                  AND CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 1), - 111.6923852740045) 
                ) 
              ) 
            ) 
          ) 
      ) f 
    WHERE recid1 = 1
```

So, pulling both, I then pull STDistance for both the GeoPoint and the GeomPoint like so:

```
select top 10 
 try_cast(GeoPoint.STDistance(@gpoint) as  float) DistanceGeo,
 try_cast(GeoMPoint.STDistance(@point.MakeValid()) as float) DistanceGeom
from #temp
```

but what I'm getting is a little weird:

```
    DistanceGeo     DistanceGeom
    -----------------------------------------
    10495.1674191715    0.111544285781801
    10249.4175883919    0.100540150724826
    12307.1907929483    0.1262738924781
    11804.655587608     0.116453906202276
    10249.4175883919    0.100540150724826
    9607.03640753812    0.101614826463312
    11130.8413059431    0.100596791997409
    10249.4175883919    0.100540150724826
    6973.69243171186    0.0644901191669685
    9605.88647121359    0.0967178499759486
```

From what I understand SRID determines unit of measure for the spatial column, but obviously, since both of these are SRID 4326 that is not the case?  Any help would be appreciated. I *believe* what I'm seeing here is degrees instead of meters. Is there an easy way in SQL to convert degrees to meters? Or a way to change what unit STDistance uses for output?

Comment: There's a [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com) where you're more likely to get a good answer, I'd expect.

Answer (score 18):

You can get a definitive answer on which unit of measurement STDistance is using with the following query. For 4326 (for example), it's the meter.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.spatial_reference_systems
WHERE spatial_reference_id = 4326
```

Comment: This returns Metres

Comment: Actually, within at least PostgreSQL 10.6, the query `SELECT srtext
FROM public.spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = 4326;` returns `UNIT`s of type `"degree"`.

Comment: Coincidentally, even though the query _returns_ "metres" for SQL Server, looking at my data shows it **is** degrees! So much for definitive.

Comment: how does this answer the question of the difference in units between `geography::STDistance` and `geometry::STDistance`

Answer (score 6):

With SqlGeomety, you are dealing with "projected coordinates".

In your case, using SqlGeometry with WGS84 (4326), your units are degrees.
So STDistance(), STArea(), ... will return degrees.

You have to use a projected coordinate system that uses meters (like Lambert 93 for france or UTM for USA) to have coordinates in meters and calculations in meters.

Answer (score 1):

Geometry assumes a flat map, geography takes in the shape of the earth. Remember the distance between lattitudes and longitudes vary dependant on where on the globe you are (at the north pole, the distances between longitudes is near 0).

If you want to bring out the big differences, put in a few more extreme examples into your code...pick a point near the north pole and another one a few degree's away. Compare that to a couple points on the equator...geometric distance and geography distance are two very seperate terms

Comment: Ya, i'm starting to feel like I've been led astray on this anyway... i had read a post where a guy had opted to use geometry instead of geography for a performance gain due to the bounding box you can set with geom, but i'm guessing he was querying over a very small dataset and over small distances.. i'm getting 2x results using geometry with srid 4326 on distances @ 10 miles and under... i'm not seeing any real gain either so I think i may abandon this...

Comment: Depends on what you are looking for I guess.  If you are going closest point to another point, then geometry would work fine as they are relative to each other.  If you are looking for distances in meters, you can't depend on the geometry.  You seem to have a different question than the one asked...are you doing this for performance gain?

Comment: more or less, but here is the issue and why this just won't work:  geometry:  244,853 , geography:  115,450 ....   the original issue is that i had run a query with 3 different geography polygons and got some very very strange results, where when i ran the same query using geometry instead the results seemed "right."  (in that case, they were 10x less than the geography...)  plus sql server doesn't render out the geography results so i had visual confirmation that it seemed the geometry query was running properly with the spatial results viewer thingie...